# How to remove ↵ symbol from string using .replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data that I am trying to scrape and save to JSON but I'm getting this symbol "↵"

For example my data is this -

```
<span class="tracktime">06:21
- 15.26 mb</span>
```

I am trying to save the duration only using -

```js
'duration': $(this).find('span[class="tracktime"]').text().trim().replace(/\↵/g, " ").trim().split(" ")[0]
```

but the data I am getting back is -

```
duration: "06:21↵-"
```

I have also tried this with no luck -

```
.replace(/\r\n/g, "")
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Try the following `/\r\n/g`

Comment: `↵` usually denotes a newline character, not a literal `↵`.

Comment: Does your data _actually_ have the unicode symbol `↵` (U+21B5) in it, or is that your editor showing you newlines, which for matching and replacement purposes are `\n`, not `↵`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not work with `substr`?

```js
let text = document 
  .querySelector('.tracktime')
  .textContent
  .trim()
  .substr(0, 5);

console.log(text);
```

```html
<span class="tracktime">06:21
- 15.26 mb</span>
```

If all you want to achieve is replacing the new line, go like this:

```js
let text = document
  .querySelector('.tracktime')
  .textContent
  .trim()
  .replaceAll('\n', '');

console.log(text);
```

```html
<span class="tracktime">06:21
- 15.26 mb</span>
```